# Decompiling or interpreting XIB/NIB files on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, nib

I've investigated understanding the NIB/XIB format quite a bit, and I cannot seem to find much information on the subject. I'm interested in understanding how iOS encodes events to button presses and the like. For instance, I know that buttons and the handlers they call can be dynamically allocated, but I'm specifically interested in knowing how to decode the NIB/XIB so that I can know which click event is called for a given button. I'd be interesting in knowing how the IBOutlets connect and how I might know what function is reachable from a certain event.

I've developing an automatic testing framework and this feature would greatly help the usability of my tool. Thanks a lot for any insight you might provide.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a format description here:

https://github.com/matsmattsson/nibsqueeze/blob/master/NibArchive.md

Also, to clarify: These nib files in question, both in XML (bplist) and "NIBArchive" format, are *compiled* nibs that can't be viewed with Xcode nor processed by `ibtool`.

See also my related question: [Extract translatable strings from "NIBArchive" .nib files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75272270/43615)

Comment: Basically just repeats your answer to the other question. Don't do that. If this question is answered by your other question's answer, vote to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @matt , this question is more general, while mine is specific for the .strings entries, otherwise I'd agree to merge them.

Comment: Either your other answer answers this question or it doesn't. If it doesn't then what's the nonintersecting content of this one?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the .xib file in a text editor, you will see that it is encoded in XML. The arrangement  XML nodes describes the structure of the view hierarchy, as well as values to be assigned to given key paths or control states of those views. You can see IBAction connections described like so:

```
<connections>
    <action selector="buttonPressed:" destination="-1" eventType="touchUpInside" id="290"/>
</connections>
```

The selector of any action connection should be implemented by the File's Owner, which you can find as the first element under the `<objects>` section. It will look like this:

```
<placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="SomeViewController">
```

It is also important to note the `<resources>` section, that describes any resources (usually images) that are used by the xib.

Comment: I should have clarified, I rarely see them in this format. They are almost always in the NibArchive format and I'm wondering how to view or unarchive that as well. Thank you for your helpful reply.

Comment: Xcode6-beta, however I am interested in providing a framework backwards compatible with most versions of xcode.

Comment: click on one of your xib files in Xcode and look at the file inspector in the Utilities toolbar on the right. What settings do you have for the drop down menus under Interface Builder Document?

Comment: Eh, I'm looking for a programatic way to do this. Using xcode is not an option in my end user environment.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to use xcode except to figure out the version of .xib that you're trying to decode. the implementation of xibs has gone through multiple iterations, the newest of which is the plain, readable XML